# Can not move to page when I click the image (using gem 'rinku')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Gem:Rinku and trying to combine an image with a link that someone add from browser.
But there is no image on the browser when I write below code and just url link on the page.

show.html.erb

```
<div class="posted_share_item_link">
  <%= Rinku.auto_link(@item.item_link, :all, 'target="_blank"').html_safe do %>
     <%= image_tag "amazon_logo.jpg", class:"amazon_image" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I thought it works if I use do-end and put image_tag in it but actually it doesn't.
so, that would be great if someone knows how I can fix it.
Thank you.

the link is not active
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fixed version.

```
 <div class="posted_share_item_link"><%= Rinku.auto_link(@item.item_link, :all, 'target="_blank"') do %>
     <%= image_tag "amazon_logo.jpg", class:"amazon_image" %>
    <% end %>.html_safe
```

You should call `html_safe` on end of chain instead of middle. In your version, you passed block to result of `html_safe` which is string and that's why it didn't work

Comment: oh, sorry I just wrote it by mistake and I wrote ``<div class="posted_share_item_link"><%= Rinku.auto_link(@item.item_link, :all, 'target="_blank"').html_safe do %>
     <%= image_tag "amazon_logo.jpg", class:"amazon_image" %>
     <% end %>
     </div> `` on my vs code.
And, i fixed it on the question.

Comment: Just add `</div>` to my solution and it's going to work

Comment: yeah I already added ``</div>`` but there is the same problem still...
just URL link is coming up and no image ..

Comment: Please move `.html_safe` to `end` like I did in my answer...

Comment: sorry I didn't notice your message and also I didn't understand what you said sorry but I tried it like you said but actually it doesn't work like I posted. The link is not active when I put ``.html_safe`` to ``<% end %>``...